# ScrollMagic: update scene state

Tags: jquery, animation, gsap, scrollmagic

I use ScrollMagic for pinning and to trigger animation. In my project I want different animations to be triggered depending on the scroll direction. Here's a representation of the project:

http://jsfiddle.net/cubius/orcpb036/10/

```
var scene = new ScrollScene({
    offset: 200,
    duration: 0
})
    .on("start", function (e) {
    if (e.scrollDirection === "FORWARD") {
        moveOutTimeline.stop();
        moveInTimeline.play(0);
    } else {
        moveInTimeline.stop();
        moveOutTimeline.play(0);
    }
}).addTo(controller);
```

First you scroll down and watch the ballon move to the right. Then you scroll up and watch the balloon move to the left :) And then you scroll down again and expect the balloon to move to the right from its current position, but instead of doing so it snaps to the center as for the first time. The animation ignores the current state of things.

So the question is: how to update the scene state and make the balloon always move from its current position?

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
new ScrollScene({triggerElement: "div.square.good"})
    .on("enter", function () {
        TweenMax.to("div.square.good", 1, {left: "90%", ease: Bounce.easeOut})
    })
    .on("leave", function () {
        TweenMax.to("div.square.good", 1, {left: "0%", ease: Bounce.easeOut})
    })
    .addTo(ctrl);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xd2dkode/5/

regards,
J